# Placing text over an image

Tags: html, css

I want to place the text and headers I added in my code above the image I set in. Every time I center the text, the image is always covering it. The text and headers I have has to be above the image and not under.

```css
#eventcenterimg {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#starting-info {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 40vh;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<img src="img/correaevent.png" height="970" alt="" id="eventcenterimg">
<div class="correa-events-info">

  <h4 id="starting-info">Book and experience any special events at Correa Events Center.</h4>
  <h4 id="starting-info">Call to book at:</h4>
</div>
<div class="socialmedia">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/people/Correas-Event-Center/100077040368594/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Try setting `z-index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an alternative minimal solution, you could also set `z-index: -1` for the `<img>` as a quick fix, without making changes on other elements.

Example:

```
#eventcenterimg {
  /*  Add this */
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried your code yet, but if the case is just about things covering something else. Try changing this:

- Set your text's z-index to 2 (set it in your styling)

I hope that works

Comment: thank you seneca. this helps out a lot

Answer (score 0):

only use absolute positioning when you have to.  Use flex

```css
#eventcenterimg {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  /*position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -17%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat; */
}

.starting-info {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
    intitial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Correa Events</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id='container'>
    
    <div class="correa-events-info">

      <h4 class="starting-info">Book and experience any special events at Correa Events Center.</h4>
      <h4 class="starting-info">Call to book at:</h4>
    </div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" height="970" alt="" id="eventcenterimg">
    <div class="socialmedia">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/people/Correas-Event-Center/100077040368594/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```